# Is there a way to DNS query from React Native or native modules?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, networking, dns

I am in need of reading TXT data from the DNS of a domain and so far nothing came useful, except using ProcessBuilder on Android to natively call nslookup.

```
(new ProcessBuilder("nslookup -q=txt DOMAIN")).start().getInputStream();
```

However, this throws a Permission Denied exception. Nonetheless, is there a simpler way to do this directly from React Native? Or if not, what would be the best approach to implement it in both Android and iOS, and what are the security implications?